# Восстановление Oracle базы через RMan

Tags: oracle

Имеется Oracle XE, работает в режиме noarchivelog, сделал backup базы с помощью

`rman> backup database;`

На момент создания backup у меня была таблица `SCOTT.BIG_TABLE`

Далее удаляю таблицу `drop table big_table;`
И опишу шаги восстановления:

1. `rman> shutdown immediate;`
2. удаляю два файла:

   \fast_recovery_area\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_1_FMLTSC4P_.LOG

   \fast_recovery_area\XE\ONLINELOG\O1_MF_2_FMLTSD63_.LOG
3. `rman> startup mount;`
4. `rman> restore database;`
5. `rman> recover database;`
6. `rman> alter database open resetlogs;`

Все происходит без ошибок. НО! Если я выполняю шаг 2 (удаляю файлы из onlinelog), то таблица BIG_TABLE возвращается.
Если же делаю те же самые шаги, но без пункта 2., то таблицы у вновь открытой базы по прежнему нет.
Почему так происходит? Как восстановить backup не удаляя вручную файлы? (странная штука).

Comment: Я не совсем понял вашу логику. Вы востановили базу, сделали recovery и для меня ожидаемый результат, что таблицы не будет. Для вас же это не ожидаемый результат. Почему вы считаете, что таблица должна  вернутся?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

не удаляя онлайн-логи вы выполняете полное восстановление базы, до последней транзакции, вместе с удалением таблицы.
чтобы восстановиться до удаления - либо уберите логи, либо сделайте [неполное восстановление](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/BRADV/rcmflash.htm#BRADV89753), указав номер лога или время до которого восстанавливать:

```
recover database until ...;
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, напишите поподробнее, что вы предлагаете?

Answer (score 0):

```
1. >rman target

2. rman> startup nomount;

3. rman> restore controlfile %path%

4. delete files

5. rman> startup mount;

6. rman> catalog start with '%path%'; -выполняется в том случае если путь не прописан в pfile:init.ora

7. rman> restore database;

8. rman> recover database; или rman> recover database until sequence=segment; - segment - указывается сигмент базы до повреждения

9. rman> alter database open resetlogs;
```

Comment: что такое "delete files"?

Comment: удаляете свои два файла

Comment: В чем смысл ответа? Я ведь так и написал, что если удаляю два файла - то всё ок. Вопрос в  том - зачем их удалять и почему если их не удалять - то таблицы big_table нет после restore?

Comment: попробуйте не удалять! этот порядок команд тоже будет работать!

Comment: вы смеетесь надо мной? Если не удалять файлы - то таблицы big_table не будет. Я об этом написал изначально.

Comment: нет, Ваша причина уникальный случай надо базу смотреть!